# Rails 3 - how to work with data got from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, syntax-error, each

I am loading from database the only row. The data are stored in variable (e.g.) @data.
In view, if I want to display the value got from database, I have to do following:

```
    <% @data.each do |d| %>
        <%=d.name %>
    <%end%>
```

And I would like to ask you - exist any better way? I think it's a bit silly for the only row to use loop... I tried something like

```
<%= @data.name %>
OR
<%= @data.each.name %>
```

But in both cases I got the error message about bad syntax...

So to my question - is possible to get display data a bit more elegantly?

**EDIT:** my query: **@data = Car.includes(:tyres).where("param1 = ?", params[:param1])**

Answer (score 1):

If you've loaded more than one model (row), then a loop is the natural construct for displaying each value. If you're really set on a one-liner, you could use some of Ruby's list comprehensions:

```
<%= @data.map(&:name).join(" ") -%>
```

Comment: yea, I am loading data from 2 models, specifically: `@data = Car.includes(:tyres).where("param1 = ?", params[:param1])`

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are loading `.all` instead of `.first`.

In your controller,

```
@data = Data.where(:some => 'condition').first
```

or

```
@data = Data.find(params[:id])
```